# Apply a custom Spark Aggregator on multiple columns (Spark 2.0)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I've created a custom `Aggregator[]` for Strings.

I would like to apply it on all columns of a `DataFrame` where all columns are strings, but column number is arbitrary.

I'm stuck in writing the right expression. I would like to write something like this :

```scala
df.agg( df.columns.map( c => myagg(df(c)) ) : _*)
```

which is obviously wrong given the various interfaces.

I had a look to `RelationalGroupedDataset.agg(expr: Column, exprs: Column*)` code, but I'm not familiar with expression manipulation.

Any idea ?

Comment: Please show your aggregator code. and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AssafMendelson, actually we plan to have many custom Aggregators for various stats, on various data types. I'm starting small with an aggregator to get shortest and longest strings : class ShortestLongestAggregator() extends Aggregator[String, (String, String), (String, String)] . For now I'd want to have all the (shortest, longest) pairs for all the columns of an arbitrary dataframe (given it only has string columns).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In contrast to `UserDefinedAggregateFunctions`, which operate on individual fields (columns), `Aggregtors` expects a complete `Row` / value.

If you want and `Aggregator` which can be used as in your snippet it has to be parametrized by the column name and use `Row` as a value type.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders, Row}

case class Max(col: String) 
    extends Aggregator[Row, Int, Int] with Serializable {

  def zero = Int.MinValue
  def reduce(acc: Int, x: Row) =
    Math.max(acc, Option(x.getAs[Int](col)).getOrElse(zero))

  def merge(acc1: Int, acc2: Int) = Math.max(acc1, acc2)
  def finish(acc: Int) = acc

  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Int] = Encoders.scalaInt
  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Int] = Encoders.scalaInt
}
```

Example usage:

```scala
val df = Seq((1, None, 3), (4, Some(5), -6)).toDF("x", "y", "z")

@transient val exprs = df.columns.map(c => Max(c).toColumn.alias(s"max($c)"))

df.agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*)
```

```
+------+------+------+
|max(x)|max(y)|max(z)|
+------+------+------+
|     4|     5|     3|
+------+------+------+
```

Arguably `Aggregators` make much more sense when combined with statically typed `Datasets` than `Dataset<Row>`.

Depending on your requirements you could also aggregate multiple columns on a single pass using `Seq[_]` accumulator and processing a whole `Row` (record) in a single `merge` call.

Comment: ```value toDF is not a member of Seq[(Int, Option[Int], Int)]

val df = Seq((1, None, 3), (4, Some(5), -6)).toDF("x", "y", "z")
```